# How to decode this encrypted javascript?

Tags: javascript, decode

How can I decode this javascript?
Can you help me?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    var _0x6af5=["\x45\x20\x31\x51\x28\x48\x29\x7B\x6A\x3D\x28\x31\x42\x29\x3F\x31\x62\x2E\x31\x79\x28\x28\x47\x2E\x68\x2B\x31\x29\x2A\x31\x62\x2E\x31\x7A\x28\x29\x29\x3A\x30\x3B\x6E\x3D\x31\x4F\x20\x31\x64\x28\x29\x3B\x43\x2E\x4B\x28\x27\x3C\x31\x37\x3E\x27\x29\x3B\x44\x28\x65\x20\x69\x3D\x30\x3B\x69\x3C\x31\x78\x3B\x69\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x65\x20\x66\x3D\x48\x2E\x31\x34\x2E\x66\x5B\x69\x5D\x3B\x65\x20\x59\x3D\x66\x2E\x77\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x65\x20\x56\x3B\x65\x20\x72\x3B\x67\x28\x69\x3D\x3D\x48\x2E\x31\x34\x2E\x66\x2E\x68\x29\x75\x3B\x44\x28\x65\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x66\x2E\x6C\x2E\x68\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x67\x28\x66\x2E\x6C\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x78\x3D\x3D\x27\x31\x50\x27\x29\x7B\x72\x3D\x66\x2E\x6C\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x6F\x3B\x75\x7D\x7D\x44\x28\x65\x20\x6B\x3D\x30\x3B\x6B\x3C\x66\x2E\x6C\x2E\x68\x3B\x6B\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x67\x28\x66\x2E\x6C\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x78\x3D\x3D\x27\x31\x73\x27\x26\x26\x66\x2E\x6C\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x31\x74\x3D\x3D\x27\x31\x75\x2F\x55\x27\x29\x7B\x56\x3D\x66\x2E\x6C\x5B\x6B\x5D\x2E\x77\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x20\x22\x29\x5B\x30\x5D\x3B\x75\x7D\x7D\x67\x28\x22\x52\x22\x51\x20\x66\x29\x7B\x65\x20\x41\x3D\x66\x2E\x52\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x31\x63\x20\x67\x28\x22\x5A\x22\x51\x20\x66\x29\x7B\x65\x20\x41\x3D\x66\x2E\x5A\x2E\x24\x74\x7D\x31\x63\x20\x65\x20\x41\x3D\x22\x22\x3B\x42\x3D\x66\x2E\x31\x71\x2E\x24\x74\x3B\x67\x28\x6A\x3E\x47\x2E\x68\x2D\x31\x29\x6A\x3D\x30\x3B\x6E\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x47\x5B\x6A\x5D\x3B\x73\x3D\x41\x3B\x61\x3D\x73\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x3C\x6E\x22\x29\x3B\x62\x3D\x73\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x50\x3D\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x61\x29\x3B\x63\x3D\x73\x2E\x4C\x28\x22\x5C\x22\x22\x2C\x62\x2B\x35\x29\x3B\x64\x3D\x73\x2E\x31\x4C\x28\x62\x2B\x35\x2C\x63\x2D\x62\x2D\x35\x29\x3B\x67\x28\x28\x61\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x62\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x63\x21\x3D\x2D\x31\x29\x26\x26\x28\x64\x21\x3D\x22\x22\x29\x29\x6E\x5B\x69\x5D\x3D\x64\x3B\x65\x20\x46\x3D\x5B\x31\x2C\x32\x2C\x33\x2C\x34\x2C\x35\x2C\x36\x2C\x37\x2C\x38\x2C\x39\x2C\x31\x30\x2C\x31\x31\x2C\x31\x32\x5D\x3B\x65\x20\x53\x3D\x5B\x22\x31\x65\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x66\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x67\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x68\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x69\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6A\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6B\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6C\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6D\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6E\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x6F\x22\x2C\x22\x31\x70\x22\x5D\x3B\x65\x20\x54\x3D\x42\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x2D\x22\x29\x5B\x32\x5D\x2E\x31\x72\x28\x30\x2C\x32\x29\x3B\x65\x20\x6D\x3D\x42\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x2D\x22\x29\x5B\x31\x5D\x3B\x65\x20\x79\x3D\x42\x2E\x7A\x28\x22\x2D\x22\x29\x5B\x30\x5D\x3B\x44\x28\x65\x20\x71\x3D\x30\x3B\x71\x3C\x46\x2E\x68\x3B\x71\x2B\x2B\x29\x7B\x67\x28\x31\x76\x28\x6D\x29\x3D\x3D\x46\x5B\x71\x5D\x29\x7B\x6D\x3D\x53\x5B\x71\x5D\x3B\x75\x7D\x7D\x65\x20\x31\x77\x3D\x54\x2B\x27\x20\x27\x2B\x6D\x2B\x27\x20\x27\x2B\x79\x3B\x65\x20\x57\x3D\x27\x3C\x58\x20\x76\x3D\x22\x31\x41\x22\x3E\x3C\x4F\x20\x76\x3D\x22\x31\x43\x22\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x6F\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x72\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x3C\x6E\x20\x31\x44\x3D\x22\x31\x45\x22\x20\x31\x46\x3D\x22\x31\x47\x22\x20\x76\x3D\x22\x31\x48\x22\x20\x50\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x6E\x5B\x69\x5D\x2B\x27\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x4F\x3E\x3C\x70\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x76\x3D\x22\x31\x4A\x22\x20\x6F\x3D\x22\x27\x2B\x72\x2B\x27\x22\x3E\x27\x2B\x59\x2B\x27\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x70\x3E\x3C\x2F\x58\x3E\x27\x3B\x43\x2E\x4B\x28\x57\x29\x3B\x6A\x2B\x2B\x7D\x43\x2E\x4B\x28\x27\x3C\x2F\x31\x37\x3E\x27\x29\x7D\x24\x28\x43\x29\x2E\x31\x4B\x28\x45\x28\x29\x7B\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x33\x27\x29\x2E\x55\x28\x22\x31\x4D\x20\x31\x4E\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x6F\x3D\x27\x4D\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x35\x2E\x31\x36\x2E\x4E\x2F\x27\x20\x78\x3D\x27\x31\x38\x27\x20\x31\x39\x3D\x27\x31\x61\x27\x20\x77\x3D\x27\x4A\x20\x49\x27\x3E\x31\x52\x20\x49\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x20\x31\x53\x20\x3C\x61\x20\x6F\x3D\x27\x4D\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x54\x2E\x4E\x2F\x27\x20\x78\x3D\x27\x31\x38\x27\x20\x31\x39\x3D\x27\x31\x61\x27\x20\x77\x3D\x27\x4A\x20\x49\x27\x3E\x31\x55\x20\x4A\x20\x31\x56\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x22\x29\x3B\x31\x57\x28\x45\x28\x29\x7B\x67\x28\x21\x24\x28\x27\x23\x31\x33\x3A\x31\x58\x27\x29\x2E\x68\x29\x31\x59\x2E\x31\x5A\x2E\x6F\x3D\x27\x4D\x3A\x2F\x2F\x31\x35\x2E\x31\x36\x2E\x4E\x2F\x27\x7D\x2C\x31\x49\x29\x7D\x29\x3B","\x7C","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x76\x61\x72\x7C\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79\x7C\x69\x66\x7C\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B\x7C\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x7C\x68\x72\x65\x66\x7C\x7C\x75\x32\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x75\x72\x6C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x62\x72\x65\x61\x6B\x7C\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x7C\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x65\x6C\x7C\x7C\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x64\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x66\x6F\x72\x7C\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x7C\x6D\x6F\x6E\x74\x68\x7C\x69\x6D\x67\x72\x7C\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x7C\x54\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x42\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x7C\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65\x7C\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66\x7C\x68\x74\x74\x70\x7C\x63\x6F\x6D\x7C\x64\x69\x76\x7C\x73\x72\x63\x7C\x69\x6E\x7C\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x6D\x6F\x6E\x74\x68\x32\x7C\x64\x61\x79\x7C\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x7C\x70\x63\x6D\x7C\x74\x72\x74\x64\x7C\x6C\x69\x7C\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x7C\x7C\x7C\x7C\x6D\x79\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x7C\x66\x65\x65\x64\x7C\x77\x77\x77\x7C\x73\x6F\x72\x61\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x73\x7C\x75\x6C\x7C\x64\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x7C\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x7C\x5F\x62\x6C\x61\x6E\x6B\x7C\x4D\x61\x74\x68\x7C\x65\x6C\x73\x65\x7C\x41\x72\x72\x61\x79\x7C\x4A\x61\x6E\x7C\x46\x65\x62\x7C\x4D\x61\x72\x7C\x41\x70\x72\x7C\x4D\x61\x79\x7C\x4A\x75\x6E\x7C\x4A\x75\x6C\x7C\x41\x75\x67\x7C\x53\x65\x70\x7C\x4F\x63\x74\x7C\x4E\x6F\x76\x7C\x44\x65\x63\x7C\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x64\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x7C\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x69\x65\x73\x7C\x74\x79\x70\x65\x7C\x74\x65\x78\x74\x7C\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x49\x6E\x74\x7C\x64\x61\x79\x73\x74\x72\x7C\x6E\x75\x6D\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x31\x7C\x66\x6C\x6F\x6F\x72\x7C\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x7C\x63\x61\x72\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x52\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x49\x6D\x67\x7C\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x7C\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68\x7C\x31\x37\x30\x7C\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74\x7C\x32\x35\x30\x7C\x61\x6C\x69\x67\x6E\x6E\x6F\x6E\x65\x7C\x33\x30\x30\x30\x7C\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x72\x5F\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x7C\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x7C\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x7C\x43\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x64\x7C\x42\x79\x7C\x6E\x65\x77\x7C\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65\x7C\x73\x68\x6F\x77\x72\x65\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x7C\x53\x6F\x72\x61\x7C\x61\x6E\x64\x7C\x6D\x79\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x67\x65\x72\x74\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x4D\x79\x7C\x54\x68\x65\x6D\x65\x73\x7C\x73\x65\x74\x49\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x76\x61\x6C\x7C\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65\x7C\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77\x7C\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","","\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x5C\x77\x2B","\x5C\x62","\x67"];eval(function (_0xd751x1,_0xd751x2,_0xd751x3,_0xd751x4,_0xd751x5,_0xd751x6){_0xd751x5=function (_0xd751x3){return (_0xd751x3<_0xd751x2?_0x6af5[4]:_0xd751x5(parseInt(_0xd751x3/_0xd751x2)))+((_0xd751x3=_0xd751x3%_0xd751x2)>35?String[_0x6af5[5]](_0xd751x3+29):_0xd751x3.toString(36));} ;if(!_0x6af5[4][_0x6af5[6]](/^/,String)){while(_0xd751x3--){_0xd751x6[_0xd751x5(_0xd751x3)]=_0xd751x4[_0xd751x3]||_0xd751x5(_0xd751x3);} ;_0xd751x4=[function (_0xd751x5){return _0xd751x6[_0xd751x5];} ];_0xd751x5=function (){return _0x6af5[7];} ;_0xd751x3=1;} ;while(_0xd751x3--){if(_0xd751x4[_0xd751x3]){_0xd751x1=_0xd751x1[_0x6af5[6]]( new RegExp(_0x6af5[8]+_0xd751x5(_0xd751x3)+_0x6af5[8],_0x6af5[9]),_0xd751x4[_0xd751x3]);} ;} ;return _0xd751x1;} (_0x6af5[0],62,124,_0x6af5[3][_0x6af5[2]](_0x6af5[1]),0,{}));

    //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Malzilla](http://malzilla.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) as described in this [SO answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2117), I got this code:

```
function showrecentposts(json)
 {
   j=(showRandomImg)?Math.floor((imgr.length+1)*Math.random()):0;
   img=new Array();
   document.write('<ul>');
   for(var i=0;   i<numposts1;   i++)
   {
     var entry=json.feed.entry[i];
     var posttitle=entry.title.$t;
     var pcm;
     var posturl;
     if(i==json.feed.entry.length
     )break;
     for(var k=0;
     k<entry.link.length;
     k++)
     {
       if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate')
       {
         posturl=entry.link[k].href;
         break
       }

     }
     for(var k=0;
     k<entry.link.length;
     k++)
     {
       if(entry.link[k].rel=='replies'&&entry.link[k].type=='text/html')
       {
         pcm=entry.link[k].title.split(" ")[0];
         break
       }

     }
     if("content"in entry)
     {
       var postcontent=entry.content.$t
     }
     else if("summary"in entry)
     {
       var postcontent=entry.summary.$t
     }
     else var postcontent="";
     postdate=entry.published.$t;
     if(j>imgr.length-1)j=0;
     img[i]=imgr[j];
     s=postcontent;
     a=s.indexOf("<img");
     b=s.indexOf("src=\"",a);
     c=s.indexOf("\"",b+5);
     d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);
     if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!=""))img[i]=d;
     var month=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
     var month2=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
     var day=postdate.split("-")[2].substring(0,2);
     var m=postdate.split("-")[1];
     var y=postdate.split("-")[0];
     for(var u2=0;
     u2<month.length;
     u2++)
     {
       if(parseInt(m)==month[u2])
       {
         m=month2[u2];
         break
       }

     }
     var daystr=day+' '+m+' '+y;
     var trtd='<li class="car"><div class="thumb"><a href="'+posturl+'"><img width="170" height="250" class="alignnone" src="'+img[i]+'"/></a></div><p><a class="slider_title" href="'+posturl+'">'+posttitle+'</a></p></li>';
     document.write(trtd);
     j++
   }
   document.write('</ul>')
 }
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('#mycontent').html("Created By <a href='http://www.soratemplates.com/' rel='dofollow' target='_blank' title='Blogger Templates'>Sora Templates</a> and <a href='http://mybloggerthemes.com/' rel='dofollow' target='_blank' title='Blogger Templates'>My Blogger Themes</a>");
   setInterval(function()
   {
     if(!$('#mycontent:visible').length)window.location.href='http://www.soratemplates.com/'
   }
   ,3000)
 }
 );
```